# No such file or directory error when using celery

Tags: python, celery, ioerror

this is my first time using Celery. I want to do a task where it will search for a file in a directory and process it.

My code so far `tasks.py`

```
from celery import Celery
import os

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

path = 'the_files'

@app.task
def do_task_txt():
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
                # string manipulation in the file
            with open(file) as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                for line in lines:
                    #date = line[0:8]
                    #time = line[10:17]
                    timestamp = line[0:27].replace(" ", "")
                    data = line[35:].replace(" ", "")
                f.close()
    return timestamp, data
```

I have a text file inside a subdirectory `/the_files`. This is the tree for the directory

```
test_celery
    ├── tasks.py
    ├── the_files
           ├── test.txt
```

`test.txt` contains several line like this

```
3/14/2009 20:08:24 1861400-6  <--- Receive Command:01010108 00606E422D4E
....
....
```

I run the worker then when I execute the task, it give me the following error

```
[2017-03-21 17:18:51,012: ERROR/PoolWorker-3] Task tasks.do_task_txt[1723fa86-30c2-40a3-accc-faef3a38c092] raised unexpected: IOError(2, 'No such file or directory')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/Fang/workspace/test_celery/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 367, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/Users/Fang/workspace/test_celery/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 622, in __protected_call__
return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Fang/workspace/test_celery/tasks.py", line 14, in do_task_txt
with open(file) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'
```

If the error pointing at the name of the path, it might be how I wrote the name of the path that produced the error but what about when it pointing at the filename?

Thank you for your help and suggestion.

Comment: Try giving it an absolute path. Your Celery worker clearly isn't looking for "test.txt" in "the_files" directory.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but that did not work. I change the following line `path = 'the_files'` to `path = '/Users/Fang/workspace/test_celery/the_files'` but it shows the same error `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'`

Comment: @Fang I wonder if you have solved this problem. I am facing something similar.

Comment: @MiniGunnR it's an old question and I am not working on this project anymore but as I could remember, I played with the path while executing the celery command. For example "celera -A path1.path2.path3 worker" or something like that. You could refer to celery documentation for the execution command.

Comment: @Fang Thanks for your reply. I was wondering if you faced the problem after using Celery in daemon mode. If I run Celery from terminal it works, but my daemon doesn't work.

Comment: @MiniGunnR I'm afraid I can't help you with that. As far as I can remember, I don't use Celery in daemon mode. Maybe you could open a new thread/ask a new question specifically for this problem.